# Joint Density Function Problem Find Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with joint density function

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}24xy& \text{for } x>0,\; y>0,\; 0<x+y<1\\ 
0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

What is the conditional probability 
$$P\left(X < \frac 12 \;\left|\; Y = \frac 14\right)\right.$$

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left[x<\frac12\right]$ denote the function that takes value $1$ if $x<\frac12$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then: $$\Pr\left(X<\frac12\mid Y=\frac14\right)=\frac{\int\left[x<\frac12\right]f(x,\frac14)dx}{\int f(x,\frac14)dx}\tag1$$

The function $g$ prescribed by:$$u\mapsto\frac{f(u,\frac14)}{\int f(x,\frac14)dx}\tag2$$ can be interpreted as the PDF of $X$ under condition $Y=\frac14$.

Observe that $(1)$ can also be written as: $$\int\left[x<\frac12\right]g(x)dx\tag3$$

Comment: Thank you. But how do you evaluate P(Y=1/4)?

Comment: It is not necessary to evaluate $P(Y=\frac14)$. Working out the integral at the RHS of (1) is enough to find the mentioned conditional probability. If you are still curious: $P(Y=\frac14)=0$ because $Y$ is an (absolutely) **continuous** random variable.

Comment: So I need to integrate this one, ∫ 24xy g(x) dx ?

Comment: What are you trying to find by that integration? In order to find $\Pr(X<\frac12\mid Y=\frac14)$ you must find the RHS of (1) or (equivalently)  (3).

Comment: P(X<1/2|Y=1/4) = P(X<1/2 union Y=1/4) / P(Y=1/4). This is my initial step in my computation.

Comment: No, that method cannot be used in this context. Especially because we are dealing with $\Pr(Y=\frac14)=0$. In general $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ but in special case $P(B)=0$ that becomes: $P(A|B)0=0$ which is true for **any** value of $P(A|B)$ (so gives us no information at all). That makes the method useless. BTW, it is not "union" but "intersection".

Comment: Yes. Intersection haha. My bad.

Comment: Twice your bad? Once is enough ;-).

Comment: Oh I see.  So how did you arrive to the RHS in (1) if you did not use P(A|B)P(B)=P(A∩B)?

Comment: By looking at the original PDF on the line $y=\frac14$. In other words: by focusing on the condition $Y=\frac14$. In $f(x,\frac14)$ we see a function that is "almost" the PDF under that condition. There is only one thing missing. It is possible that $\int f(x,\frac14)\neq1$ which is necessary for a PDF. To repair that we divide the function by a suitable constant: $c=\int f(x,\frac14)dx$.

Comment: Ok. But what is the equivalent of ∫[x<1/2]f(x,1/4)dx? Should I integrate it from 0 to 1/2?

Comment: If I am to evaluate RHS of (1). I would get ∫[x<1/2] 6x dx / ∫ 6x dx. What is [x<1/2]?

Comment: Formally $\int[x<\frac12]f(x,\frac14)dx=\int^{\frac12}_{-\infty}f(x,\frac14)$, but because $f(x,\frac14)=0$ for $x<0$ you can indeed integrate from $0$ to $\frac12$. I have got to go now.

Comment: Yes. Of course. Thank you .